# Isomers through Nucleophillic substitution

Tags: reaction-mechanism

If a single active optical isomer of 2-chlorobutane were to undergo a nucleophillic substitution reaction with iodide ions, how many optical isomers are present in the product? A mixture? Or just a single isomer?

My attempt:
Iodine can only approach the carbon atom from the opposite side of chlorine(the point at which chlorine is bonded)due to repulsion. So a single isomer is obtained as a product.

However, many of my friends are saying my logic is incorrect. Can somebody please clarify this?

Comment: How is the logic incorrect?

Comment: They stated that two isomers will be formed- laevorotatory and dextrorotatory isomers.

Comment: (i) there is a single isomer ... (ii) this can undergo either a SN1 reaction or a SN2 reaction.  An SN1 reaction will give two products; an SN2 reaction will give one product.  You need to know whether the reaction is SN1 or SN2 to be able to answer the question.

Comment: I used SN2 reaction(the one in which carbon gets bonded to five groups for intermediate?). Btw is the reasoning I provided correct for SN2?

Comment: @Faiq Raees You may have some misconceptions about Intermediates versus Transition States, and Pentavalent Carbons. SN2 is the reaction you are thinking of, but there is no Intermediate (the reaction occurs in a single concerted step) and the carbon in the transition state does not actually have five bonds, two of them are depicted as "partial bonds" in the imaginary process of breaking/forming.